# How to reduce storage (scale down) my AWS RDS instance?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a AWS RDS (Postgres) instance with storage SSD 1000 GB, but the data is only 100 GB of size.

How can I scale down the storage resource of AWS RDS easily?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

RDS does not allow you to reduce the amount of storage allocated to a database instance, only increase it.

To move your database to less storage you would have to create a new RDS instance with your desired storage space, then use something like pg_dump/pg_restore to move the data from the old database to the new one.

Also be aware that an RDS instance with 1,000GB of SSD storage has a base IOPS of 3,000. An RDS instance with 100GB of SSD storage has a base IOPS of 300, with occasional bursts of up to 3,000.

Comment: @Dave I don't see anything in that article about changing the storage volume size. That article is related to changing the Instance size, i.e. the amount of CPU and RAM available. Not disk space.

Comment: still true, asked their support. Even after dropping DBs billable size does not reduce.

Comment: Apart from the database specific utility like pg_dump mentioned in the answer, you can also use AWS Database Migration Service. Here is a [getting started](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_GettingStarted.html) link for the same.

Comment: please keep in mind that DMS does not work smoothly with JSON fields and you might not be able to take advantage of, already wasted ~4 hours on it

Comment: @rooby IOPS (storage volume) burst is separate from CPU burst. You are referring to CPU burst in your comment, but my answer is referring to storage volume burst.

Comment: @MarkB you're right. Sorry, I confused the two. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 18):

Based on AWS's help [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html), this is the full process that worked for me:

1) **Dump the database to a file**: run this on a machine that has network access to the database:

`pg_dump -Fc -v -h your-rds-endpoint.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -U your-username your-databasename > your-databasename.dump`

2) In the AWS console, create a new RDS instance with smaller storage. (You probably want to set it up with the same username, password, and database name.)

3) **Restore the database on the new RDS instance**: run this command (obviously on the same machine as the previous command):

`pg_restore -v -h the-new-rds-endpoint.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -U your-username -d your-databasename your-databasename.dump`

(Note, in step 3, that I'm using the endpoint of the new RDS instance. Also note there's no `:5432` at the end of the endpoint addresses.)

Answer (score 9):

Amazon doesn't allow to reduce size of HDD of RDS instance, you may have two options to reduce size of storage.

1:-if you can afford downtimes, then mysqldump backup of old instance can be restored to new instance having lesser storage size.

2:- You can use Database migration service to move data from one instance to another instance without any downtime.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the Database Migration Service. It almost worked for me - until I discovered that it doesn't (currently) support proper migration of JSON or JSONB columns :-(

Comment: Here is the guide from Amazon: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-db-storage-size/

Answer (score 4):

When using RDS, instead of doing typical hardware "capacity planning", you just provisioning just enough disk space for short or medium term (depends), expand it when needed.

As @Mark B mentioned , you need to watchout the IOPS as well. You can use "provisioned IOPS" if you need high performance DB.

You should make you cost vs performance adjustment before jump into the disk space storage part. 
E.g. if you reduce 1000GB to 120GB , for US west, you will save 0.125x 880GB = 110/month.  But the Max IOPS will be 120x 3 = 360IOPS

It will cost you $0.10 to provision additional IOPS to increase performance. Say if you actually need 800IOPS for higher online user response,
(800-360) x 0.10 = $44.  So the actual saving may eventually "less". You will not save any money if your RDS need constant 1100 IOPS. And also other discount factor may come into play.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by migrating the DB to Aurora.

If you don't want Aurora, the Data Migration Service is the best option in my opinion. We're moving production to Aurora, so this didn't matter, and we can always get it back out of Aurora using `pg_dump` or DMS. (I assume this will apply to MySQL as well, but haven't tested it.)

My specific goal was to reduce RDS Postgres final snapshot sizes after decommissioning some instances that were initially created with 1TB+ storage each.

1. Create the normal snapshot. The full provisioned storage size is allocated to the snapshot.
2. Upgrade the snapshot to an engine version supported by Aurora, if not already supported. I chose 10.7.
3. Migrate the snapshot to Aurora. This creates a new Aurora DB.
4. Snapshot the new Aurora DB. The snapshot storage size starts as the full provisioned size, but drops to actual used storage after completion.
5. Remove the new Aurora DB.
6. Confirm your Aurora snapshot is good by restoring it again and poking around in the new new DB until you're satisfied that the original snapshots can be deleted.
7. Remove new new Aurora DB and original snapshot.

You can stop at 3 if you want and just use the Aurora DB going forward.

Answer (score 1):

The #2 answer does not work on Windows 10 because, per this [dba overflow question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35112/issues-with-encoding-and-pg-dump-restore-between-windows-and-linux), the shell re-encodes the output when the `>` operator is used. The `pg_dump` will generate a file, but the `pg_restore` gives the cryptic error:

```
pg_restore: [archiver] did not find magic string in file header
```

Add `-E UTF8` and `-f` instead of `>`:

```
pg_dump -Fc -v -E UTF8 -h your-rds-endpoint.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -U your-username your-databasename -f your-databasename.dump
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a read replica with smaller disk space, promote it to standalone, and then switch that to be primary.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33461895)